# NS_ERROR_FAILURE in Firefox on setting font of canvas inside a hidden iframe

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, iframe, html5-canvas

I am trying to create a text editor using a `canvas`.

To place the cursor at the right position I need to calculate the width of every character.

I am caching the width of each character on initial load.

This works fine on Firefox when launched directly but throws an error (`NS_ERROR_FAILURE`) when launched inside an `iframe` whose parent is hidden.

I've narrowed down this case in a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/maitreyjukar/0dff1r67/).

Can anyone help me out with the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an iframe set to `display:none`. If you really think you need an invisible iframe [you can do this](https://jsfiddle.net/fs92he7r/1/):

```
.frame-wrapper {
  z-index: -1231231;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  height:1px; width:1px;
  opacity:0;
}
```

But if all you're doing is running an invisible canvas you can do that in javascript.

Comment: This is what I'm already doing. My question here is, why would Firefox not let me set any values on the CanvasContext?

Comment: @mjzeus - According to your fiddle you were *not* already doing that. You had `display:none` on the frame which was causing the initial error. By changing it to `opacity:0` you get rid of that error. If you have a question about setting the values you need to include more information, like where are you setting the values from, the parent frame or the child frame. I've fixed the problem in your fiddle, I'm not going to guess all the possible uses and every possible error that could potentially come up next. If you have another problem post another question.