# Drawing in canvas not working in iframe when in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, html5-canvas

Hello I am trying to make a simulation of a ruler measuring a desk. The mousemove event works when I open the simulation [alone](https://physiquiz.gr/wp-content/uploads/html/fe1.html) but not when I open it in an iframe like [here](https://physiquiz.gr/a1/). The iframe works when opened with Chrome or Opera but not with Firefox. It also works with Edge after I press F12. Please help I am just a teacher not a developer and browser compatibility is far beyond my understanding.

Update: After the answer of murphy1312 I also noticed that my problem is also because the iframe is in a hidden tab that loads initially with `display:none`. Is there something I can do in the iframe document without changing anything in the parent page?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48303223/ns-error-failure-in-firefox-on-setting-font-of-canvas-inside-a-hidden-iframe

Comment: That user gets the exact same error with me but the response he gets is too specific and cannot be applied in my case. Any response that can help me with this and every time I find this NS_ERROR_FAILURE ?